# Superscrollorama - Tweens for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

This shouldn't be too complicated, although I've been hung up on it. I'm using [Superscrollorama](http://johnpolacek.github.com/superscrollorama/), a jQuery plugin for animations to occur when the element is scrolled into the center of the browser.

If I want to have two elements that both fade when they reach the middle of the browser in different areas of the page, I need to create two separate tweens in the JavaScript. I can't have one fade element that shares a class being referenced in the script. This is because once the first fade element is hit, it sets off both animations. Here's a snippet of code that won't work how I want it to:

```
<!--HTML-->
<h2 class="fade-it">Fade It</h2>
<h2 class="fade-it">Fade It again</h2>

<!--JavaScript-->
var controller = $.superscrollorama();
controller.addTween('.fade-it', TweenMax.from( $('.fade-it'), .5, {css:{opacity: 0}}));
```

And the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RPRzW/143/). Sorry if I didn't explain it properly, it's a bit difficult to word. The main point of this is to reduce code. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is right there in your description. You're right: you can't have one fade element that shares a class without both being triggered.  Give the two elements separate id's and make create two separate tweens using their id's, not the shared class.

Comment: That's kind of what I thought, but I figure I'd ask to make sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use two separate tweens. That's how it's intended to work.